# Selecting nodes before a node which contains a string via Xpath

Tags: xpath

Let's assume that I have the following XML. I would like to select all the nodes before the node which contains the text `MAGIC` except its parents. (Because I will delete them later on)

```
<body>
<div>//Should NOT be selected
   <div>some</div> 
   <div>  //Should NOT be selected
      <p>sth</p>  
      <hr /> 
      <br /> 
      <p>some not important MAGIC text</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this XPath :

```
//*[following::*[contains(., 'MAGIC')]]
```

or this one if the node containing text `MAGIC` is always a `<p>` element :

```
//*[following::p[contains(., 'MAGIC')]]
```

Given html input in this question, the output when I tested using an online XPath tester is as follow :

```
Element='<div>some</div>'
Element='<p>sth</p>'
Element='<hr />'
Element='<br />'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
//*[following-sibling::*[contains(text(), 'MAGIC')]]
```

In contrast to [har07's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035297/1816580), this will look only for the element directly containing the magic text and select the *siblings* and not all elements before it regardless of nesting level.

You can also reverse the selector:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'MAGIC')]/preceding-sibling::*
```